# How to use function from another project witch are linked in Tizen native app

Tags: c, header-files, tizen-native-app

I'm trying to use function from another project witch are linked. I use serviceMqtt like a service and BasicUI2 just to display content. When i get a message in serviceMqtt, I want to display on watch (BasicUI2).

//Function in BasicUI2 project (basicui2.c)

```
void _label_click_count_text_set(char text[])
{
   elm_object_text_set(detail_text2, text);
}
```

This is code of header file in project BasicUI2 (basicui2.h)

```
#ifndef __basicui2_H__
#define __basicui2_H__

#include <app.h>
#include <Elementary.h>
#include <system_settings.h>
#include <efl_extension.h>
#include <dlog.h>

#ifdef  LOG_TAG
#undef  LOG_TAG
#endif
#define LOG_TAG "basicui2"

#if !defined(PACKAGE)
#define PACKAGE "org.example.basicui"
void _label_click_count_text_set(char text[]);
#endif

#endif /* __basicui2_H__ */
```

I included this file in project ServiceMqtt, `#include "basicui2.h"`.
Before that, I declared path BasicUI2/inc in ServiceMqtt->Properties->C/C++ General->Path and Symbols->GNU C  to use header file (basicui2.h)

Problem:
When i tried to use function _label_click_count_text_set(some_text); in ServiceMqtt (servicemqtt.c), I got an error:

```
undefined reference to `_label_click_count_text_set`
```

Question:
How to solve this problem or how to display message received on wearable?
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYYhS.png)

[Two linked projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VuoY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Application Control between Service App and UI App.
Refer to this page: https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/native-application/application-management/application-controls